# Wrapper not extending all the way down the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code is at the bottom, it does not work because alot of the files are on my computer but it shows the basic concept this are pictures of my website

[Scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL4Lk.jpg)

[Unscrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46Tlt.jpg)

So as you can see on the first image that is scrolled down there is a blank space which is annoying since the height is 65%. The second image is just an unscrolled one.

So my question is how can I make it go from 65% to the bottom of the screen. By the way I can not make this `position:fixed` because then I could not scroll through the games when I add more.

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/DBjloQv.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  -webkit-background-size:cover;
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
ul.nav{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  position:absolute;
  bottom:65.5%;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
}
li.nav{
  float:left;
}
a.nav:visited,a.nav:link{
  color:rgb(230,230,230);
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  padding:14px 16px;
  font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
a.nav:hover{
  color:rgb(255,255,255);
}
.active{
  color:rgb(255,255,255) !important;
}
div.bg{
  position:absolute;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
  text-align:center;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
  height:65%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}
div.game{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  width:279px;
  height:375px;
  margin:5px 11px;
  border-radius:1px;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/rGCA5cd.png);
  -webkit-background-size:cover;
  background-size:cover;
  cursor:pointer;
}
div.gametext{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:25%;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  color:white;
  font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:20px;
}
p.gametext{
  color:white;
  font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Home - <?php $activeid=0; include"php/globalvars.php";echo $name;?></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/home.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="bg">
      <div class="game" id="4"><div class="gametext"><p class="gametext">Battlefield 4</p></div></div>
      <div class="game" id="22"><div class="gametext"><p class="gametext">Battlefield 1</p></div></div>
      <div class="game" id="19"><div class="gametext"><p class="gametext">Rocket League</p></div></div>
  </div>
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav"><a href="index.php" class="nav active" onclick="return false;">Logo Here</a></li>
    <li class="nav" style="float:right;"><a href="signin.php" class="nav>Sign In</a></li>
  </ul>
  <?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
      $href;
      switch($_GET['id']){
        case 4:
          $href="Battlefield4";
          break;
        case 22:
          $href="Battlefield1";
          break;
        case 19:
          $href="RocketLeague";
          break;
      }
      Header("Location: /game/".$href.".php");
    }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your code into your question. You can do this using Ctrl+M. You can add both HTML and CSS.

Comment: Just go to the codepen.

Comment: Yes, I know. But if some day this link is broken, the question is not valid anymore to future visitors to this question.

Comment: Ok I added the code in

Comment: Thank you! Now I want to know what is really your problem because I cannot see your problem at all.

Comment: Just look at pictures.

Comment: I guess that you are looking to remove the bottom translucent space at the bottom but I am not totally secure.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/bwWxAKy.jpg That is the problem, so when it is the size of an iphone the bg wrapper does not extend all the way down

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure why it's scrolling just a bit, but if you add

```
  overflow: hidden;
```

on the parent of bg (your  tag) it stops scrolling.

new css:

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

to make the games scroll, I think you might add a  wrapper with this style:

```
div.scroller {
  display: block;
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

I updated the pen with a bunch more games that scroll the way I think you're going for.

(added the specific css from the codepen to the answer)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGdBRx

To allow the content to scroll over the whole window, while keeping the bg section where it is, don't make the game divs children of the bg.

See updated codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pNROvQ

Comment: Now it wont scroll, I added overflow:hidden to html,body. Then I added a wrapper around the bg that has the games in it and set it to height:100% and overflow:scroll.

Comment: Check out the codepen in my answer.  It works for me.  Didn't mention you need to set display: block as well to get it to scroll.

Comment: How can I make it scrollable on an iphone?

Comment: Nevermind it works. Although is there any way I can make them have to scroll down page instead of scrolling down that 1 box?

Comment: What I mean by that is how can I make so that the navbar(You can see that in photo) will follow the scroll.

Comment: See updated codepen.  You don't need bg to be a parent of the game divs.  It may be that was also why you were having trouble with it scrolling, too.